# Flutter PageView dynamic height

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I created a `PageView` with a fixed value but it is an issue. How i am gonna convert this to dynamic height? `SizedBox` is in a `Column`'s child. I tried `Expanded` and `Flexible` widgets but they did not work.

```
        class BranchViewBottomSection extends ConsumerWidget {
  const BranchViewBottomSection({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
    required this.branchId,
    required this.companyId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Map<String, dynamic> data;
  final String branchId;
  final String companyId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: data['available_sections'].length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (data['available_sections'][index]["branchTabValue"] ==
                      ref.read(tabIndexProvider)) {
                    return BranchSectionBox(
                        data: data, index: index, isActive: true);
                  } else {
                    return BranchSectionBox(
                        data: data, index: index, isActive: false);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              PageRouteBuilder(
                pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                    MenuView(
                  branchId: branchId,
                  companyId: companyId,
                  branchData: data,
                ),
                transitionsBuilder:
                    (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                  const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
                  const end = Offset.zero;
                  const curve = Curves.ease;

                  final tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end);
                  final curvedAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
                    parent: animation,
                    curve: curve,
                  );

                  return SlideTransition(
                    position: tween.animate(curvedAnimation),
                    child: child,
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.pink,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                "Sipariş vermek için dokunun.",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: PageView(
            onPageChanged: (v) {
              ref.watch(tabIndexProvider.notifier).state =
                  data['available_sections'][v]['branchTabValue'];
            },
            children: <Widget>[
              BranchViewHomePage(),
              BranchViewDetailsPage(),
              const BranchViewCommentsPage(),
              BranchViewContactPage(),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the parent.

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names, file_names

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:neshapp/comps/common/MainCircularProgressIndicator.dart';
import 'package:neshapp/services/FirestoreService.dart';
import 'package:neshapp/utils/constants.dart';

import '../../providers/BranchViewProviders.dart';
import '../../providers/MenuProviders.dart';
import 'BranchSectionBoxes.dart';

class BranchView extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String branchId;
  final String companyId;
  final String tableNo;
  const BranchView(
      {Key? key,
      required this.branchId,
      required this.companyId,
      required this.tableNo})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    /*
    Uygulamanın her yerinde kullanabilmek için eğer bir şubeye
    girilirse şubenin ve markanın id'lerini providerlara veriyorum.
     */
    ref.watch(branchIdProvider.notifier).setId(branchId);
    ref.watch(companyIdProvider.notifier).setId(companyId);
    ref.watch(tableNoProvider.notifier).setTable(tableNo);

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          future: FirestoreService.getBranchData(companyId, branchId),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              final data = snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return CustomScrollView(
                scrollBehavior: const ScrollBehavior(),
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverAppBar(
                    elevation: 0,
                    title: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("${data['branch_name']} Şubesi"),
                        FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                          future: FirestoreService.getCompanyData(companyId),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.done) {
                              final CData =
                                  snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                              return Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: constsColor.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                ),
                                child: Image.network(CData['company_logo']),
                              );
                            } else {
                              return const MainCircularProgressIndicator();
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    pinned: true,
                    expandedHeight: 200,
                    backgroundColor: constsColor.neshMoru,
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      background: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(data['branch_image']),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 10,
                              right: 10,
                              child: Text(
                                tableNo,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: constsColor.white,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: BranchViewBottomSection(
                      data: data,
                      branchId: branchId,
                      companyId: companyId,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: MainCircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the parents? column etc.

Comment: Okay i added others.

Comment: Expanded widget should be working. What error are you getting exactly? Otherwise, the 'BranchViewBottomSection' widget is not in the list?

Comment: `The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.` I am gettingn this error.

Comment: Is BranchViewBottomSection widget inside a list widget?

Comment: It inside a `CustomScrollView` widget. I added parent widgets.

Answer (score -1):

expand and flexible i believe are both depend on the parten widget.

how about using the state for that ?

Comment: It can work. Do you have any idea to implement this?